# How to display images larger than 256x256 in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, size, imagelist

ListView is connected to ImageList in order to display images.
The maximum size of image in ImageList is 256x256.

I tried to add larger image in ImageList, but an exception occurs. On the following line:

```
imageList.ImageSize = new Size(300, 300);
```

`"Value of '300' is not valid for 'ImageSize.Width'. 'ImageSize.Width' should be between 1 and 256.\r\nParameter name: ImageSize"`

Is there a way to display larger images in ListView? For example 512x512 or bigger?

Comment: Either change code to allow larger images in Listview or use a utility that decrease the resolution from 512x512 to 256x256.

Comment: [ImageList.ImageSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#property-value).

Comment: How to do that? ImageList throws exception.

Comment: To do what? Have you read the referred link? Not possible. Besides, 256+ is too big to display in a scrollable control.

Comment: It's known limitation of ImageList. The point of this question is how to overcome this limitation, and show bigger images in ListView. Like Windows Explorer can show Icons 512x512, etc...

Answer (score 0):

With [DPI Awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process), you can use images larger than 256 in higher Windows resolutions. For example, with 150% Windows scale settings (Settings, Scale and Layout), the ImageList.Size limit is 256 * 1.5 or 384. At 250%, the limit is 256 * 2.5. At 100% scale the limit is 256.

The display resolution might have some influence. I haven't found any of this in documentation.

Comment: sorry, not usefull